# Passing checkbox value to save / Do not save Password via react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase auth I will want to add a Check box or Switch, it will save the password for next login and Do not save it when it is clicked again

How to Passing checkbox value to save / Do not save Password?

**This is my Login Page Code:**

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            response: ''
        }
        this.signUp = this.signUp.bind(this)
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
    }

    async signUp() {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            this.setState({
                response: 'Account Created!'
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.navigator.push({
                    id: 'App'
                })
            }, 500)
        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({
                response: error.toString()
            })
        }
    }
    async login() {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
            this.setState({
                response: 'user login in'
            })

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.navigator.push({
                    id: 'App'
                })
            })

        } catch (error) {
            this.setState({
                response: error.toString()
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.containerInputes}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholderTextColor="gray"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholderTextColor="gray"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        style={styles.inputText}
                        password={true}
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                    />
                    <Switch

                    />
                    <Text>Click to save your password</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.login}
                    style={[styles.loginButton, styles.button]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.textButton}
                    >Login</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <TouchableHighlight
                    onPress={this.signUp}
                    style={[styles.loginButton, styles.button]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.textButton}
                    >Signup</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use AsyncStorage, if the checkbox is clicked then save the info to the device and retrieve it when the page loads to display. If checkbox is not clicked, don't save it.

Comment: Thank you @Matt , Do you have any sample example?