# Adding an eye icon on the right side of the input field in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native project. I have a password field on the Login page and I want to add an eye icon on the right end of the input field. My code currently looks like this:

```
  <View><TextInput placeholder='Enter your Password' autoCorrect={false} secureTextEntry={true} textContentType='password'></TextInput></View>
```

This is a normal input field with a placeholder text.

Comment: check if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628346/passing-checkbox-value-to-show-hide-password-via-react-native

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find the below code:

```
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');  
const [isPasswordSecure, setIsPasswordSecure] = useState(true);


<View style={styles.viewPassword}>
                    <TextInput
                      secureTextEntry={isPasswordSecure}
                      style={styles.textInputStyle}
                      right={
                        <TextInput.Icon
                          name={() => <MaterialCommunityIcons name={isPasswordSecure ? "eye-off" : "eye"} size={28} color={COLORS.black} />} // where <Icon /> is any component from vector-icons or anything else
                          onPress={() => { isPasswordSecure ? setIsPasswordSecure(false) : setIsPasswordSecure(true) }}
                        />
                      }
                      fontFamily={FONTS.ROBOTO_REGULAR}
                      fontSize={Theme.FONT_18PX}
                      selectionColor={COLORS.orange}
                      underlineColor={COLORS.orange}
                      label={StringsConstants.Password}
                      value={password}
                      onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
                      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                      theme={{ colors: { text: COLORS.black, primary: COLORS.orange, placeholder: COLORS.black } }}
                    />
</View>
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: Yeah!! It works! But I couldn't access the 'right' property of the TextInput Field until I installed 'react-native-paper'. Anyway, Thank You!

Comment: Anytime Most Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

you can put it and style it like this

```
<View>
<TextInput placeholder='Enter your Password' autoCorrect={false} secureTextEntry={true} textContentType='password' />
<EyeIconOrImage style={{
position: 'absolute',
right: 20,
}} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this custom component out. Use your own styles, I have used NativeWind for styling

```js
import { Pressable, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

import { Feather } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import React from "react";
import { COLORS } from "../../../styles/globalStyles";
import PrimaryText from "../texts/PrimaryText";

type Props = {
  val: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  setVal: (val: string) => void;
  label: string;
  isOptional?: boolean;
  showErrorMessage?: boolean;
  errorMessage?: string;
  isNumeric?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  isPassword?: boolean;
};

const InputFieldWithLabel = ({
  val,
  placeholder = "Please Input Here",
  setVal,
  label,
  isOptional = false,
  showErrorMessage = false,
  errorMessage = "This field is required",
  isNumeric = false,
  disabled = false,
  isPassword = false,
}: Props) => {
  const [hidePassword, setHidePassword] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <View className="w-full">
      <PrimaryText variants="label1">
        {label} {isOptional && "(Optional)"}
      </PrimaryText>
      <View className="mt-4 bg-blue-100">
        <TextInput
          value={val}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChangeText={(val) => setVal(val)}
          className={`w-full rounded border  px-4 py-2 ${showErrorMessage ? "border-primary-100" : "border-neutral-gray-3"} ${disabled ? "bg-neutral-gray-2 text-neutral-gray-4" : "bg-neutral-white text-neutral-black"}`}
          keyboardType={isNumeric ? "numeric" : "default"}
          style={{ fontFamily: "AnekBangla_400Regular" }}
          editable={!disabled}
          secureTextEntry={isPassword ? !!hidePassword : false}
          cursorColor={COLORS.primary[100]}
        />
        {isPassword && (
          <Pressable
            onPress={() => setHidePassword(!hidePassword)}
            className="absolute right-4 top-3 z-10"
          >
            {hidePassword ? (
              <Feather name="eye" size={24} color={COLORS.neutral.black} />
            ) : (
              <Feather name="eye-off" size={24} color={COLORS.neutral.black} />
            )}
          </Pressable>
        )}
      </View>

      {showErrorMessage && (
        <PrimaryText variants="label3" className="mt-1 text-primary-100">
          {errorMessage}
        </PrimaryText>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputFieldWithLabel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this fully customizable TextInput with eye icon in the right of the input field , This is in (js)  Convert to (ts) before use.

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { colors, fonts, images } from '../constants';

const InputText = ({
  error,
  labelName,
  labelChild,
  value,
  placeholder,
  onSubmitEditing,
  onChangeText,
  keyboardType,
  secureTextEntry,
  multiline,
  returnKeyType,
  autoFocus,
  placeholderTextColor,
  onBlur,
  errorText,
  inputref,
  inlineImageLeft,
  autoCorrect,
  style,
  onFocus,
  editable,
  maxLength,
  autoCapitalize,
  extraStyle
}) => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isPasswordVisible, setIsPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const [errorBorderColor, setErrorBorderColor] = useState(colors.lightGreen);

  useEffect(() => {
    setErrorBorderColor(error ? colors.errRed[0] : colors.lightGreen);
  }, [error]);

  const handleTogglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setIsPasswordVisible(!isPasswordVisible);
  };
  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };
  const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>{labelName} <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>{labelChild}</Text></Text>
      <View style={[styles.inputContainer, { borderColor: errorBorderColor }, extraStyle]}>
        <TextInput
          selectionColor={colors.green}
          ref={inputref}
          value={value}
          onChangeText={onChangeText}
          onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
          autoFocus={autoFocus}
          multiline={multiline}
          secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry && !isPasswordVisible}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          keyboardType={keyboardType}
          returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
          placeholderTextColor={placeholderTextColor}
          style={[styles.input, style]}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          inlineImageLeft={inlineImageLeft}
          autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
          editable={editable}
          maxLength={maxLength}
          autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
        />
        {placeholder === "password" && isFocused && (
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconContainer} onPress={handleTogglePasswordVisibility}>
            <Image
              source={isPasswordVisible ? images.eyeOpen : images.eyeClose}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      </View>
      {error && (
        <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{errorText}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputText;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 15,
    paddingRight: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 45,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: fonts.Regular,
    includeFontPadding: false,
    color: colors.placeholder,
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  label: {
    fontSize: 14,
    marginBottom: 10,
    color: colors.black,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  iconContainer: {
    padding: 8,
  },
  icon: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
  errorContainer: {
    height: 20,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  errorText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'red',
    marginTop: 5,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
});
```

Call this in your parent component as below to show the eye icon .

```js
<InputText
                      labelName={"Enter Password"}
                      labelChild={"*"}
                      autoFocus={false}
                      placeholder={"password"}
                      placeholderTextColor={colors.placeholder}
                      multiline={false}
                      returnKeyType={"done"}
                      error={passError}
                      errorText={"Enter valid password"}
                      keyboardType={"default"}
                      secureTextEntry={!showPassword}
                      value={password}
                      onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                      inputref={passRef}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      onBlur={onBlurPassword}
                      autoCapitalize={"none"}
                    />
```